# Cocoa program can't be stopped

Tags: cocoa, debugging, xcode4, exception

I'm trying to write an OS X app that uses a serial port. I found an example (cocoa) and got it running in Xcode 4. On the first run, it opens the port and I'm able to exchange data with the hardware.

If I try to change the port the program goes rogue. The pinwheel starts and the UI is unresponsive. I can't stop the program from Xcode, nor can I kill it from Terminal, or Force Quit. Force Quit of Xcode doesn't do it. Although the PID goes away with a kill from Terminal, the UI is still present with the merrily spinning pinwheel.

The only way out is a re-boot. Any ideas on how to track down the errant code are welcome. I'm new to Cocoa/Objective C, so simple terms are better.

Comment: Reminds me of the movie Speed. "If I don't keep feeding events to the run loop, it'll explode!!!" Post your code, Mike - we have no idea what you're doing or how you're doing it.

Comment: The code is probably too big to post. I can't find where I downloaded the zipped project from. I'd be happy to e-mail it to you.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it became a zombie.  It should show up in `ps auxww` (or similar) with a 'Z' in its status.  Activity Monitor might also still show it.

This is relatively common when working with hardware, such as a serial port.  Zombies can arise for either of two reasons, most likely the first in this case:

1. The process is blocked in a kernel call of some kind, that's not interruptible.
2. The process has exited but its parent hasn't acknowledged that (via wait() or similar).

In the first case it's usually a fundamental bug or design flaw of some kind, and you may not have any good options short of figuring out exactly what code path tickles the problem, and avoiding that.

In the second case the solution is generally simple - find the parent process of your zombie and kill it.  Repeat as necessary until your zombie gets adopted by a parent process that does call wait() to reap it (launchd will do this if nothing else).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. They would most likely benefit someone with more experience than i have. How would I look in ps auxww? Is Activity Monitor the big box in the center of XCode's top bar? I'll try some more stepping thru and see if I can find anything re: #1. How would I find the parent process?

Comment: Activity Monitor is in /Applications/Utilities. `ps` is something you run in Terminal. Which is also in /Applications/Utilities.